# Similarity between $I+N$ and $e^N$ when $N$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let
$$
N=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&&\\&\ddots&\ddots&\\&&0&1\\&&&0
\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}
$$
and $I$ is the identity matrix of order $n$. How to prove $I+N\sim e^N$?

**Clarification**: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similar_matrix) is the definition of similarity, which is not the same as [*equivalence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence).

**Update**:

I noticed a stronger relation, that $A\sim N$, if
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&*&*\\&\ddots&\ddots&*\\&&0&1\\&&&0
\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}
$$
and $*$'s are arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Now you can answer your question. This is explicitly encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By subtracting $I$ this is equivalent to asking about the similarity class of a nilpotent square matrix of size $N$.    The similarity type of $N$ is determined by the dimensions of the kernels of powers of $N$.  In the upper triangular case the list of dimensions of $\ker N^i$ is $1,2,3,4,...,n$ for both of the matrices you consider.  Hence they are similar.

Comment: Can you give more words on "The similarity type of $N$ is determined by the dimensions of the kernels of powers of $N$"?

Comment: Some subspace is killed by $N$, but a possibly larger space is killed by $N^2$, and a larger one by $N^3$.  Continue until you get the null space of $N^n$ which is the vector space $V$ on which $I$ and $N$ act.  If you choose (compatible) bases for all these kernels you will see that it gives a basis for $V$ and the same exercise for another operator $N'$ with the same diagram of kernel dimensions leads to another basis.  Changing from one basis to the other is the similarity.  It is easier to draw  a picture than describe in words.

Comment: Why won't the "chain" of $A^i$ terminate before $i$ reaches $n$ in the triangle case? I mean, why is it impossible that there exist a $k<n$ such that $A^k=0$?

Comment: For both of the matrices you consider, the elements immediately above the diagonal are nonzero.  You can find an ordered basis where the action is $Nv_i = a_i v_{i-1} + \ldots$ and all $a_i$ are nonzero.

Comment: I think I understand, thank you, @zyx .